# CSS meganav sub-nav div to sit at the top of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical list with hover that displays a div in a right pane. I need the right div to sit at the top of the containing div for each item.

Currently the right div is sitting beneath the list item.
Here is a fiddle **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nfV6X/1/)**

```
 <div id="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">item</a>
      <div class="dropdown_3columns">
        <div class="col_1">
          <ul class="left-list">
            <li><a href="#">item</a>
              <div class="col_2">
                <h2>Colours</h2>
                <ul id="sub-main-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a>
              <div class="col_2">
                <h2>item</h2>
                <ul id="sub-main-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a>
              <div class="col_2">
                <h2>item</h2>
                <ul id="sub-main-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a>
              <div class="col_2">
                <h2>item</h2>
                <ul id="sub-main-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a>
              <div class="col_2">
                <h2>item</h2>
                <ul id="sub-main-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a>
              <div class="col_2">
                <h2>item</h2>
                <ul id="sub-main-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">item</a>
              <div class="col_2">
                <h2>item</h2>
                <ul id="sub-main-nav">
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                  <li><a href="#">item</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col_2">
          <ul class="right-list">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I get it do do that?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to do what you want ... but you have not noticed the `h2` tags that are rendering with white text that they inherit from

```
#main-nav li{
    ...
    color:#fff;
    .... }
```

Possible solutions:

- put a background colour on the `li`s
- change the text colour of the `h2` - but watch out for specificity